# Error in declaring unordered_map which maps string to a template

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures, compiler-errors, unordered-map

```
template<typename T>
struct hash;

template<typename T> class WUG{
    public:
        WUG(){
            unordered_map<string,typename T,hash> vertexmap; //Problem
        }
};
```

I am getting some error in this code which really doesn't say anything to me. How should I declare it properly?

The error message I'm having is:
    [Error] template argument 2 is invalid
[Error] template argument 5 is invalid

Comment: It looks like you might be using `using namespace std;`. This could cause some confusion between `std::hash` and the `::hash` you've declared. An [MCVE] is in order. Additionally, the compiler is well aware that `T` names a type. It's a template argument.

Comment: your map consists of three arguments, a map takes in only two, it's like a key value pair - map<string, string>

Comment: @zenwraight That is incorrect. [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) may have as many as 5 template arguments, 3 of which provide a default value.

Comment: aah I wasn't knowing that, hmm good to learn something here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `using namespace std;` that imports all the names from the `std` namesapce including `std::hash`, fix:

```
struct MyHash;

template <typename T>
class WUG {
public:
  WUG() {
    unordered_map<string, T, MyHash> vertexmap; //Problem
  }
};
```

or with the standard hash:

```
template <typename T>
class WUG {
public:
  WUG() {
    unordered_map<string, T> vertexmap; //Problem
  }
};
```

Comment: @BatzorigZorigoo If you want to use `std::hash<T>` simply don't provide a third template argument to your map. It's the default hashing implementation used `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: @BatzorigZorigoo `std::hash` works for the `std::string` as well as many other standard types.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Nice! But I deleted using namespace std; and added std:: where its needed. But I still have the same error

Comment: @BatzorigZorigoo If you have changes to make to your question, please edit the question. If those changes would drastically change the question, post another question.